# A problem related to diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $A^k=I_n$ for some positive integer $k\geq 1$, then show that $A^2=I_n$.

Here $A$ satisfies $(x^k-1)=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\cdots+1)$. So minimal polynomial must divide it, if minimal polynomial is $(x-1)$ then result holds. but i can't further proceed. Please someone help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

They key fact is that you have stated $A$ is diagonalisable **over the real numbers**.  So we have
$$A=P\pmatrix{\lambda_1\cr &\ddots\cr &&\lambda_n\cr}P^{-1}$$
and hence
$$A^k=P\pmatrix{\lambda_1^k\cr &\ddots\cr &&\lambda_n^k\cr}P^{-1}\ .$$
Since this is the identity we have $\lambda_j^k=1$; but $\lambda_j$ is real and so $\lambda_j=\pm1$ for every $j$.  Hence
$$A^2=P\pmatrix{\lambda_1^2\cr &\ddots\cr &&\lambda_n^2\cr}P^{-1}=I\ .$$

---

If the matrix is only diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$ the result need not be true.  For example, if
$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}$$
then $A^4=I$ but $A^2\ne I$.